# how to routing auto in django with as few code as possible

Tags: python, django

l am a novice with django.

l use PHP with CI. In CI, it can route automatically. and l don't need to set too much thing

In tutorial, it created a `view.py` and defined a function `hello`, then defined a rule in `urls.py` like `url(r'^$', view.hello)`,
is there any other way can auto route url like following

set a rule like

```
url(r'^hello/(*)$', view.*)
```

then define function in view.py

```
def hello1(request):
    ...
def hello2(request):
    ...
```

then access url

`127.0.0.1:8080/hello/hello1`

`127.0.0.1:8080/hello/hello2`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

```
./manage.py
./hello_project/__init__.py
./hello_project/urls.py
./hello_project/hello/__init__.py
./hello_project/hello/urls.py
./hello_project/hello/views.py
./hello_project/settings.py
```

*./hello_project/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello/', include('hello_project.hello.urls')),
]
```

*./hello_project/hello/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello1', views.hello1),
    url(r'^hello2', views.hello2),
]
```

*./hello_project/hello/views.py*

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def hello1(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello1\n')

def hello2(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello2\n')
```

*./hello_project/settings.py*

```
..

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'hello_project.hello'
]

..
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#url

In action:

```
bash-4.4$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/hello1
hello1
bash-4.4$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/hello2
hello2
```

PS. Don't be afraid of "code" / "too many lines of code".  Look at the zen of python for inspiration.

Full source: https://files.fm/down.php?i=78kartk (available for 2 weeks, then it dies.)

Comment: but inside the `hello.urls` you will have the same list of urls without pattern

Comment: @BearBrown, its correct. Thats how the urls work, they just get appended to one another.